# Access Runtime Error '-2147352567 (8002009)' Can't assign value to this object

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime-error

I have an event that triggers every ten seconds that updates text fields within a form.

I get runtime error that I can't assign a value to an object.

The field is a text field with no restrictions or input masks. It doesn't have the error on all records. The table is formatted to short text.

```vb
'On Error GoTo ObjectError 
If [AircraftTailNumber].[Column](0) <> 0 Then 

    [WorkflowName] = [model] & "-" & [AircraftTailNumber].[Column](0) & "-(" & [DepartmentBox] & ")-" & [Scheduled Release:] & "-" & [Task_ID] & "-" & [New Description Of Model:] 

    [SmartTeam WIR:] = "WIR " & [AircraftTailNumber].[Column](0) & " " & [New Model Title:] & " REV " & [NewRevTileBox] 

    [LD# Full Name:] = "LD_" & [AircraftTailNumber].[Column](0) & "_" & [New Model Title:] & " REV " & [NewRevTileBox] & "_" & [New Description Of Model:] 

    [OffBoardEmail] = "Offboard Workflow " & [Workflow (SAV#)] & "-" & [Task_ID] & "-" & [New Model Title:] & " REV " & [NewRevTileBox] & " " & [New Model Description]
```

The records having the error today, did not have the error yesterday.
There have been no modifications to the tables and no changes to the record.
I might log on tomorrow and find there are no errors.

Update:
The db is run on a server environment, I brought the FE and BE to my desktop and it worked.
I have record level locks so maybe this has to do with logging out and logging back in and the record not resetting so it thinks someone is accessing?

Comment: The first line. If i make inactive the first line, then the next line triggers the error.  [AircraftTailNumber].[Column](0) is a combo box value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the records are locked from when i last used them, so when the timer event triggers it tries to update locked fields and causes the error. It's best practice i think to do edit record locks, but if this does happen i don't know how to unlock the record without kicking everyone off the DB and deleting the .laccdb file.